# Desfire Getting 1E (INTEGRITY_ERROR) on changeKey and changeKeySettings

Tags: mifare

I'm trying to change key and key settings but always getting same error.
List of my commands:

```
-----Authenticate 
Key: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Vector: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Command: 0A 00
Response: AF 8B 95 99 DC C7 71 F4 DB
RndB: 8B 95 99 DC C7 71 F4 DB
Decrypted RndB:3E 48 AA 0B D6 1F 2E EA
Shifted:48 AA 0B D6 1F 2E EA 3E
RnbA: 5A AC 38 6E 0E 0B 80 F4
RnbAB:5A AC 38 6E 0E 0B 80 F4 48 AA 0B D6 1F 2E EA 3E
Encrypted RndAB:F7 69 E9 95 DF A2 3E A0 5D 5F 47 A9 6A 15 40 AD
Command: AF F7 69 E9 95 DF A2 3E A0 5D 5F 47 A9 6A 15 40 AD
Response: 00 1F 59 B1 E0 AC FC BD 3E
newRnbA:1F 59 B1 E0 AC FC BD 3E
decrypted newRnbA: AC 38 6E 0E 0B 80 F4 5A
Session key: D9 1C AD FD 8D 2A 61 41 DA 5F 54 3C 7C EF 5D 37 D9 1C AD FD 8D 2A 61 41

-----ChangeKeySettings
Key: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Vector: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Session key: D9 1C AD FD 8D 2A 61 41 DA 5F 54 3C 7C EF 5D 37 D9 1C AD FD 8D 2A 61 41
New Key Setting
Crc: A9 09
Decrypted data: 0F 09 A9 00 00 00 00 00
Encrypted data: 68 31 80 24 AE 26 43 B5
Command: 54 68 31 80 24 AE 26 43 B5
Response: 1E 90 00

-----ChangeKey
Old Key: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Vector: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
New key: 00 10 20 31 40 50 60 70 80 90 A0 B0 B0 A0 90 80
CRC: 89 FF
Cryptogram: 00 10 20 31 40 50 60 70 80 90 A0 B0 B0 A0 90 80 FF 89 00 00 00 00 00 00
CryptogramEcn: 95 6D E0 F8 8F 26 83 96 E6 5D 1C 88 9E 9D EA 89 9E 8D A5 61 19 F7 90 48
Command: C4 00 95 6D E0 F8 8F 26 83 96 E6 5D 1C 88 9E 9D EA 89 9E 8D A5 61 19 F7 90 48
Response: 1E 90 00
```

Encription method is: 2K3DES

Q1: is my crc16 is right?

Q2: is my encryption is right?

Q3: If yes, what is wrong?

I'm hoping on fast help.

Thank you

Comment: How did you end up with your session key being `D9 1C AD FD 8D 2A 61 41 DA 5F 54 3C 7C EF 5D 37 D9 1C AD FD 8D 2A 61 41`? Given that your RndA is `5A AC 38 6E 0E 0B 80 F4` and your RndB is `3E 48 AA 0B D6 1F 2E EA`, the session key should be `5A AC 38 6E 3E 48 AA 0B` (note that since you authenticated using a single DES key (i.e. K1=K2), you would also only have a single DES session key).

Comment: @MichaelRoland `3E 48 AA 0B D6 1F 2E EA` is RndB'. Do have I use it without shifting? Correct RndB is `48 AA 0B D6 1F 2E EA 3E`

Comment: Your calculation above says something different. The decrypted value is RndB. You then shift it to generate RndB'. For calculating the session key you have to use RndB (the result from decryption) and *not* RndB'.